# How to Know USB device "HID" and "PID"

Tags: c#

Please advice me, is there any built in function to retrieve "PID" and "VID" when USB is hooked up to the system?  If not, what is the best way to get USB "HID" and "PID"? I need these two to detect USB HID device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your tag specifies `C#` I'm going to assume that you want to do this using Microsoft Windows.

Using Windows I find this information using Device Manager under Computer Management (right-click on `My Computer` and select `Manage`).  Using `View` -> `Devices by connection` open up the `PCI bus` node and then all of the USB nodes until you find the device you are looking for.  Below is an example from my PC showing three USB devices on `Intel(R) 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB Universal Host Controller` entries.

[image]

Then look at the properties of the device -> then details -> then select property hardware ids and you should get the VID and PID of the device.

[image]

Comment: Hello HeatFanJohn, Thanks a lot. This helps me.If there are multiple USB HID devices hooked up, will it be displayed under this section.Let me know. THanks.

Comment: Yes, multiple USB HID devices should be listed separately.  I updated the posting to use a more descriptive image.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about native .NET, I only used [LibUsbDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/) so far, check the [examples](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html).

Usually you would install the .NET assembly from the [sourcefourge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/) page, add the assembly to your Visual Studio project (References/.NET) and follow the [examples](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html) (LibUsbDotNet Example Code/Getting Startet Example).  Details depend on your C#/.NET/Visual Studio versions.

Comment: Hello Rudolf, How to use it.Do I need to download and install .exe file.